# How to display LAT/LONG of polygon?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table with geom field (type: `geometry`)

I want to display the values of the `polygon` in lat/long.

How can I do it ?

I saw this post:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95373/convert-geometry-to-latitude-longitude-using-postgis-st-transform/95376

but the functions `ST_X`, `ST_Y` only works on `POINT` and not on `POLYGON`.

How can I display the geom field (which contains polygon) in lat/long format ?

Comment: Do you mean the coordinates of the centroid, or all the coordinates that make up the polygon? Ideally, post an example polygon (in WKT) and the output you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the output you want, it might very well be that [ST_ASGEOJSON](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) already does everything you want, but otherwise, you can use [ST_DUMPPOINTS](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) to get all the individual points of the polygon.

```sql
SELECT polygon.id,
       ( SELECT ARRAY_AGG(ST_Y(geom ORDER BY path))
         FROM ST_DUMPPOINTS(polygon) AS points ) as latitudes,
       ( SELECT ARRAY_AGG(ST_X(geom ORDER BY path))
         FROM ST_DUMPPOINTS(polygon) AS points ) as longitudes
FROM polygons
```

would return ordered lists of latitudes and longitudes per polygon.
If you want to combine, them, use [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html):

```sql
SELECT polygon.id,
       ( SELECT ARRAY_AGG(
             JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                 'latitude', ST_Y(geom),
                 'longitude', ST_X(geom)
             ) ORDER BY path)
         )
         FROM ST_DUMPPOINTS(polygon) AS points )
FROM polygons
```